PromQL query to find 99th percentile request latency
I'm looking at a PromQL query we're using to fire an alert when the latency of a certain service goes beyond 400ms, but I'm unable to understand how it works, or even if it is correct at all -
The alert is summarized as

maximum of 99th percentile request latency has been > 400ms for 5m

and the underlying PromQL query for it is -
max(rate(http_server_requests_seconds{namespace="xxx",quantile="0.99",service="service-A"}[2m])) > 0.4

The http_server_requests_seconds is a SpringBoot actuator metric.
However, I'm unable to figure out if the query is doing what it says in the summary.

Based on semantics of the metric in use I conclude that http_server_requests_seconds is a quantile part of summary.
rate should not be used on quantiles of summaries. In fact, if you'll copy your query into Prometheus console, you'll get a warning

PromQL info: metric might not be a counter, name does not end in _total/_sum/_count/_bucket: "http_server_requests_seconds"

I'd say you should drop rate call, to get behaviour described in summary.
